# Empty token with Python Requests, but multiple tokens seen in chrome dev tools

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to login to a site, navigate to a page, and scrape some data. This question is about the first step (to get in).
I cannot fetch the token from the site:

```
import requests
URL = 'https://coderbyte.com/sl'
with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get(URL)
    print([response.cookies])
```

Result is empty:
`[<RequestsCookieJar[]>]`

This make sense according to the response I'm seeing in Chrome's dev tools. After I login with my username and password, I see four tokens, three of them deleted, but one valid:
[image]

How can I fetch the valid token?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the post method to the url you want in order to fetch the token (to pass the login first). For example :

```py
url = "url-goes-here"
url_login = "login-url-goes-here"

with requests.Session() as s:
    # get the link first
    s.get(url)

    payload = json.dumps({
        "email" : "your-email",
        "password" : "your-password"
    })

    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = s.post(url=url_login, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Based on your question, i assume that if you only use username or password to login, then you can use `HTTPBasicAuth()` which is provided by [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) package.